# Alignment half of text cutting off in second row

Tags: tabularx, hyphenation

I have a question about fixing a formatting issue of my table. Currently, I like the way its organized, but the problem is some words are being hyphenated, so that only half of the word appears in the 2nd line below.

how could I make the text in the 2nd column not be cutoff so that it could appear as a whole word in the second line?

My current code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{babel}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}{S[table-format=-1.2]} @{}}
    \toprule   
\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}} \\
    \midrule   
    \multirow{1}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(8,12) & 62.93 & 16.59 & -0.08 & 12.62 & 1.04  \\ \addlinespace       
\multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 15.80 & 0.29 \\     
& 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.26\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.96 & 5.07 & -0.57 & -9.38 & 0.32 \\     
& 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 10.13 & 5.19 & -0.44 & 10.87 & 0.33\\
& Top minus Bottom & 3.75 & 6.54 & 2.45 & 18.54 & 0.02\\ \addlinespace

\multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 11.76 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.28\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.38 & 5.76 & -0.59 & 8.74 & 0.25 \\     
& Top Minus Lowest & 3.38 & 5.94 & 0.68 & 11.03 & 0.00 \\     
& Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 11.79 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.27 \\     
& Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 10.04 & 5.64 & 0.03 & 13.76 & 0.34 \\     
& Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 9.04 & 5.43 & -0.73 & 8.80 & 0.30 \\     
& Highest Minus Lowest & 2.72 & 5.60 & 0.82 & 12.79 & -0.03 \\   \addlinespace

\multirow{3}{*}{ Market} & Composite Index & 5.74 & 5.47 & -0.54 & 10.10 & 0.12 \\
& Equal Weighted Index & 11.93 & 7.01 & 0.24 & 11.64 & 0.35 \\ 
& Value Weighted Index & 9.34 & 5.39 & -0.57 & 9.90 & 0.32 \\ \addlinespace

\multirow{1}{*}{Institutional} & Hedge Fund Index & 8.99 & 1.94 & -1.22 & 8.07 & 1.00\\

\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{Reality Check P-values Under Mean Performance Criterion Benchmarked Against CRSP Market Index}
\label{table: table2}
\noindent 
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYY S[table-format=1.4] @{}}  

\toprule 

\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Passive Total Return} & {\thead{Value Weighted\\ Return Index}} & {\thead{Equal Weighted\\ Return Index}} \\

\midrule  

Momentum & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \addlinespace

Size & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.72 \\ \addlinespace  

Value & 0.00 & 0.37 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace  

\bottomrule  

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A picture shows this as follows:

[image]
As can be seen, some rows such as the 2nd last two rows are being cut off and I don't think it looks that pleasing. Does any one have some advice ? I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Off-topic: You have several either redundant or conflicting statements in the preamble. E.g., you have two definitions of the `L` column type, and you have two `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` directives followed by `\setlength\parindent{0.5cm}`. Do try to remove some of the cruft from the preamble -- it'll make it so much easier to track down weird errors and maintain the code in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix I can think of is to replace

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}{S[table-format=-1.2]} @{}}
```

This will reduce the widths of columns 3 thru 7, leaving more space for column 2 (whose width is a residual, since it is calculate as `\textwidth` minus the widths of the other 6 columns.

Comment: It worked out very nicely but just for me to keep this in mind next time, how exactly did you know to type `-1.2` ? I understand that the the first part defines `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}` but I'm wondering how exactly did you determine the last part from `{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}` to `{S[table-format=-1.2]} @{}`. Thank you!

Comment: @PutsandCalls - The numbers in columns 3 thru 7 all have either 2 digits, one digit and a `-` symbol, or just one digit *before* the decimal marker, and exactly 2 digits after the decimal marker. Since the `-` symbol is wider than a digit, choosing `-1.2` sets aside enough space for all numeric data points. (For sure, `3.3` seemed excessive.) I made the change -- and noticed that the line breaks in column 2 were gone. If selecting `-1.2` hadn't been sufficient to achieve your goal, I would have gone on to tinker with `\tabcolsep`, which determines the amount of intercolumn whitespace.

Comment: I am running into some trouble again after I made some fontsize changes where my table now looks like the picture in the above post (i edited the code and the picture). I also seem to have this problem with my other tables, which is that the headings also don't seem to be aligned anymore (similar to the one I showed in the picture). Is there anyway to have it look similar before while keeping the 12pt font and 1.25 margins ? Sorry for the trouble and I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @PutsandCalls - For your revised table, I would recommend simplifying (and shortening!) three of the column headers to "Mean", "Vol.", and "Kurt.", respectively. At any rate, both mean and volatility are annualized, right? Why attached "annualized" only to the "mean" label? These three changes should make line breaks in the "Strategies" column unnecessary. If that's still happening, though, change `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright` in the definition of the `L` column type, and `\Centering` to `\centering` in the `C` column type; this will inhibit linebreaks.